# Seeking accurate WMS server for Kenya?

Tags: wms, data, resolution, africa, kenya

I am looking for an accurate Map for visualizing positional data collected in Kenya. Right now I am using EXOMAPS (https://tiles.maps.eox.at/wms), in particular, a Sentinel2 cloudless view, but I am getting as you can see a poor resolution.

[image]

The points have an average distance of 1 meter.

I was checking at the WMS Global Mosaic (https://gcmd.nasa.gov/KeywordSearch/Metadata.do?Portal=NASA&KeywordPath=Projects%7CM+-+O%7COGC%2FWMS&EntryId=NASA_JPL_WMS_GMR&MetadataView=Full&MetadataType=0&lbnode=mdlb1), but I cannot find the WMS server APIs.

I am open to suggestions. I would have like to have at least a resolution of 2 or 3 meters (as the one of Google Maps).

Comment: You can check here: http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services, you may have to use WMTS, though.

Comment: @enolan, I have checked but reading the description, there is no map in the folder that is accurate from Kenya, high resolution is available only for USA.

Comment: If you want high resolution remote sensing imagery, you will almost certainly need to pay for it ~ https://www.researchgate.net/post/Where_can_I_get_high_resolution_satellite_image

Comment: If it's open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score -1):

How about the OpenLayers Plugin and use google maps as a basemap?

Comment: That can be an idea, however I need a wms server to feed tableau map service, so should I create a custom wms?

Comment: sorry I have never heard of using google as wms and it is also not legal ive read. I think sentinel is probably the best you can go with if you are looking for free orthophotos in Africa.

Comment: Yeah and here there is the problem, I am not finding an accurate one. @Leo